# unable to install PHPunit on my local machine

Tags: phpunit, pear

I am Trying to install phpunit on my local mac machine, but I got the followings error when I ran the command below:
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

parse error in /private/etc/php.ini on line 786

Comment: What exactly is in that php.ini, and on that line?

Answer (score 0):

Check /private/etc/php.ini on line 786. There would be some parsing error.

After solving that,you can refer following blog for PHPUnit installation.

> [Installing PHPUnit On Windows](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2011/04/installing-phpunit-on-windows.html)